# Do sub queries in select statement creating any performance downgrade?

Tags: sql, oracle, performance

```
select po_number,
            (select t.full_name 
             from person t 
             where t.subscriber_id=358 
              and t.company_id=2
              and person_id=p.buyer_person_id) buyer_name 
from po_header p 
where subscriber_id=358 and company_id=2 ;
```

Please see above example. 
Guys could you please help me to understand the subquery performance in select statement?

Comment: The best way to understand perfomance is to look at execution plan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your current query:

```
select po_number,
       (select t.full_name from person t where t.subscriber_id=358 and
        t.company_id=2 and person_id=p.buyer_person_id) buyer_name
from po_header p
where subscriber_id=358 and company_id=2;
```

The subquery in the `SELECT` statement is a particular type called a *correlated* subquery.  The output of this subquery depends on, or is correlated with, the outer query.  In practice, this means that the subquery must be run for every record of the `po_header` table.  This can be costly from a performance point of view.

An alternative to what you have written would be to join your two tables, something like this:

```
SELECT
    p.po_number,
    COALESCE(t.full_name, 'NA') AS full_name
FROM po_header p
LEFT JOIN person t
    ON p.buyer_person_id = t.person_id AND
       t.subscriber_id   = 358         AND
       t.company_id      = 2
WHERE p.subscriber_id = 358 AND
      p.company_id    = 2
```

I would expect this to perform better than your original query, especially if we were to add indices to the columns involved in the join and the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Note those qurries are different a bit.  Correlated version will fail if  `t.buyer_person_id, t.subscriber_id,   t.company_id` isn't unique for a reason. Join version will just return several rows.

Comment: @Serg Of course, I am assuming that the original query is logically valid.  If not, then it would not even run.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks for your help...Let's say, we have to get person name from person table and tax_percent from TAX_CODE1 table.  Are we going to write joins for all the tables or how we can trace these scenario?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: In my experience there won't be a performance difference between those two versions. Oracle's optimizer is (very often) smart enough to rewrite the first one to an outer join internally

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Then Oracle's optimizer should open a Stack Overflow account.  It would probably do better than we are!

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I was talking about such scenarios when we need to write multiple correlated sub queries for different tables.

Comment: @msanaullah You should try, in general, to avoid such correlated subqueries, though from the above comments it seems that the Oracle optimizer might be smart enough to fix things for you.

Answer (score 1):

Well, what is there to say? For each po_header you get a certain matching person's name. We may naturally think of loops:

1. Loop through the headers.
2. For each header loop through the names and find the matching one.

But we already know that, provided an appropriate index exists, the DBMS may just use the index to find the name rather than loop through the person table. What is not so evident, however, is the fact that the DBMS is free to completely to re-write the query internally. So maybe the first thing the DBMS does instead is join the two tables and then remove what it doesn't need. Or it may create a list of all names matching the company and subscriber ID first and use this for a lookup later. The DBMS has many techniques on how to deal with tables and Oracle's optimizer is very good.

So we may guess what the DBMS actually does, or we may look at the excecution plan. Anyway, this isn't something we should waste too much time on. If the query runs fine without any obvious performance issues, then why worry? Once it shows that the query *is* slow, we'd look at the execution plan and consider which indexes to build, in this case probably something like:

```
create index idx1 on po_header(subscriber_id, company_id, buyer_person_id, po_number);
create index idx2 on person(subscriber_id, company_id, person_id, full_name);
```

The query as is looks fine and is readable and hence maintainable. I see no reason to change it much. Well, we could make the correlation clearer of course:

```
select 
  po_number,
  (
    select p.full_name 
    from person p 
    where p.subscriber_id = h.subscriber_id
      and p.company_id    = h.company_id
      and p.person_id     = h.buyer_person_id
  ) as buyer_name 
from po_header h
where subscriber_id = 358 and company_id = 2;
```